# PhoneGap: JQuery Mobile ajax fails with certificate issue

Tags: ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile, certificate

I am trying to make an ajax call using jquery mobile and ended with Certificate issue.

Code which makes Ajax call

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

    $.ajax({
        url : "https://test.stage.example.com/services.do?method=getDetails&ticket=" + window.context.getTicket(),
        success : function(data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error : function(err, status) {
            alert("err");
        }
    });
});
```

Getting below error message

> Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid.
>   You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “test.stage.example.com” which could put your confidential
>   information at risk.

**The URL which i requires VPN Connection. And, i have added the Certificate to Key Chain Access which requires for VPN connection.**

Comment: What is the "non VPN URL" that it works with?

Comment: @lan : URL which doesn't requires VPN Connection.

Comment: Yes but what does it look like! Is it on a different server or what?

Comment: yes. its working with different server